# rhandsontable drop-down menus cut short in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

When I try to edit the entries of an rhandsontable inside a Shiny app, the drop-down menus are cut short. Is there a way to make them fully expand like the date selectors in the [rhandsontable tutorial](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/86427_5e76c7578e3940d4a093fc8e259c51f6.html)? Here is the app.

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(rHandsontableOutput("data"))

server = function(input,output) {
  df = data.frame(x = factor(letters[1:3], levels = letters))
  values = reactiveValues(data = df)

  observe({
    req(input$data)
    values$data = hot_to_r(input$data)
  })

  output$data = renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work if you change the size of your `rhandsontable`.

You could try:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(rHandsontableOutput("data"))

server = function(input,output) {
  df = data.frame(x = factor(letters[1:3], levels = letters))
  values = reactiveValues(data = df)

  observe({
    req(input$data)
    values$data = hot_to_r(input$data)
  })

  output$data = renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data, height=500) 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

EDIT: Based on [this](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/120), you can use `overflow = "visible"`. It seems to fix the issue.

```
ui = fluidPage(rHandsontableOutput("data"))

server = function(input,output) {
  df = data.frame(x = factor(letters[1:3], levels = letters))
  values = reactiveValues(data = df)

  observe({
    req(input$data)
    values$data = hot_to_r(input$data)
  })

  output$data = renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(values$data, overflow = "visible") 
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you change the width of the menus too? Without increasing the width of the column.

Comment: This solution is not great because we can't vary the number of rows in the table or page size. I tried min-height in the css but then the dropdown stopped working.

Comment: Hi, is there another way to do that without touching the height of the table, which is not ideal? (in case of relative long dropdown compared to number of rows of the table for instance). Maybe by setting the z-index of the dropdown menu to a high value?

Comment: @yeahman269, see edit. Does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no it does not. Already tried it. The drop down menu is still truncated if `height` is not sufficient.

Comment: @yeahman269, maybe it's worth posting a new question with your data reproducing your problem.